# Custom useForm Hook does not update field value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the following example the name does not update:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-od9th?file=/src/index.js:0-788

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";


const useForm = initialValues => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  return [
    values,
    e => {
      console.log(e.target.value);
      setValues({
        ...values,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      });
    }
  ]
}

let count = 0;

const Hello = (props) => {
  const [values, handleChange] = useForm({ nameInput: props.name });
  count++
  console.log(`RenderedAmount: ${values.nameInput} : ${count}`)
  return (
  <div>
    Name: <input value={values.nameInput} onChange={handleChange}/><br/>
    Hello {values.nameInput}!
  </div>
);
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Hello name="John"/>, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to give the name to the input.

As you are doing `[e.target.name]: e.target.value`.

If the name of the input is undefined, you will have `{"": value}` in your state

```js
<input value={values.nameInput} onChange={handleChange} name="nameInput" />
```